# Delegate WPF Event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a WPF Project with following XAML Code:

```
 <GroupBox Name="GroupBox1">
     <GroupBox.Header>
         <WrapPanel>
             <CheckBox Name="CheckBox1"/>
             <Label Name="label1" Content="Extend" MouseLeftButtonUp="Label_Click" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

I have more than one of this GroupBoxes. I want to change `Checkbox1.IsChecked` property by clicking on `label1`.

Currently I have in my code-behind:

```
private void Label_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox1.IsChecked = !CheckBox1.IsChecked;
}
```

I would like avoid writing that action for each `GroupBox`.

**Question:** How can I get the `checkBox1` dynamically from `sender` in `Label_Click` .

Comment: You can share a single event handler for all your group boxes, retrieve the parent panel using `((Label)sender).Parent` and then get the associated check box from the parent's children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this handler to your labels:

```
private void Label_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Label lb = (Label) sender;
    WrapPanel wp = (WrapPanel) lb.Parent;
    CheckBox cb= wp.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (cb!= null)
    {            
        cb.IsChecked = !cb.IsChecked;
    }
}
```

Edited the code regarding to vc 74 comment. @vc 74: thx

Comment: Just did it ;) Thx for your feedback :)

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
private void Label_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var checkbox = ((sender as Label).Parent as WrapPanel).Children.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault();
   checkbox.IsChecked = !checkbox.IsChecked;
}
```